# What is the correct usage of "P.S." in Emails?

Tags: style, email

I've been wondering this for a while. What is the correct usage of "P.S." in e-mails? Where should and shouldn't it be used?

Comment: Uhm, maybe I'm wrong, but to me this question looks more related to "how to write an e-mail" rather than something strictly related to English...

Comment: @Alenanno Uhm, most probably you might be wrong. Because there is no such a thing like P.S. in Turkish. At least, not that I know of.

Comment: What about French, Spanish, Italian, German? If I copied and pasted this question in any of those SE sites (pretending some of them already exist), the question would "fit"... Unless you're asking for something specifically about English usage of P.S., then I'd be wrong.

Comment: I don't get the votes to close. P.S. is a linguistic element, and email is a linguistic medium. The proper usage is a reasonable thing to ask about, even if it's not easy to arrive at a concensus.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'll tell you my point of view: I didn't exactly voted to close, I voted to migrate the questions to the Writers SE. I think it is far more related to the question than this SE does, in my opinion. This is a question about style, not about English.

Comment: @Alenanno: I don't suppose you'll be persuaded, and there are already 4 votes to close, so you're obviously not alone. I still think it's about *usage of the English language*, not a style question as I understand writers.se

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But I'd like to know why you think it's about English usage... Really, I mean... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Postscript still useful in the age of email?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/is-postscript-still-useful-in-the-age-of-email)

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate of http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/is-postscript-still-useful-in-the-age-of-email

Comment: @Alenanno: Having trawled over some more writers.se questions for the first time in months, I see they *do* actually cover things like this, so I'm retreating somewhat from my earlier position. But EL&U has often overlapped in the general area - witness that outrageous viral question about *nested [sic]'s* - and originally I hadn't realised writers.se went much further than helping out budding authors.

Comment: This is borderline writers/English, so I think we should be inclusive and allow this here. It's also *kind of* a dupe of an existing question - it got a flag for that - with a slightly different spin. To that user, thanks for flagging, but I think it fails the test of answers interchangeable between the two questions = duplicate.

Comment: I think you take yourselves too seriously. You state a valid opinion about formal emails, especially if the person you are addressing is relatively unknown to you and is judging your email as an indicator of how well you conform to the principles of Brevity and Clarity but informal emails among friends a postscript can add a sense of intimacy and a stylistic tradition sometimes lost in the digital process. I still have friends who argue the supremacy of digital over analog when it comes to music when actually the subjective "ear of the beholder" is also a valid, if personal, point of "view."

Comment: I am so glad this got asked. +1 million

Comment: I just recently used it in the following way: Hello [email recipient], I wanted to provide you with some preliminary information regarding your presentation topic so that you will have time to prepare. I will provide further updates regarding the day’s agenda and room location(s) early next week. (continued)

Comment: Please be prepared to present on the following: Describe the considerations impacting first-generation college students and their families when seeking financial aid. Your presentation should last approximately 20 minutes, with an additional 10-15 minutes for Q&A. Thank you, [email sender]

P.S. Happy belated birthday!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**P.S.** in e-mails is used exactly the same as **P.S.** in normal letters.  It is short for the Latin **post scriptum**, i.e. written *after* the main script.  As such, it is written at the bottom (end) of the main script (main e-mail in this case), and generally contains information which is trivial, or tangental to what was just said.  For example,

> I'm starting my new job on Monday.  Really looking forward to it.  I'm going to be working as a clothes designer.
>
> P.S. Do you still like making clothes?

Comment: I know it's only an example, but if I got an email from someone I didn't know well enough to already *know* what their new job was going to be, that particular P.S. wouldn't seem trivial or tangential to me. I'd assume [s]he was sounding me out to work on making up the clothes [s]he was going to be designing! :-)

Comment: To be exact, Post Scriptum means "after what has been written"... By the way, Post Scriptum can also contain important information, the real feature is that you wrote it after you finished the letter, because you forgot to write it in the main body... And here I kind of agree with @FumbleFingers, in "formal" e-mails, it might sound weird... Maybe if they are informal, it can be ignored.

Comment: P.S. goes after the signature.

Answer (score 33):

Personally I think **P.S.** is *never* really 'appropriate' in emails.

The whole point of a post-scriptum is it's something you think of *after* the main text has already been written. By which time in the old days of pen-and-ink you'd have already written your closing lines, and most likely signed it as well.

With electronic writing such as emails, just go back and add the extra text in the main body. Don't insult your reader by subjecting him to badly-organised text just because you can't be bothered to organise it before you click on Send.

Comment: So should books (written on computers, typewriter or with pen) never have footnotes, or does it mean the author was too lazy to go back and edit the main body? I know PS and footnotes are not quite the same thing, but I think they could be used in similar ways.

Comment: @Hugo: Footnotes are quite common in the kind of 'pop science' books I often read, but to be honest I don't really like them that much. I'm never sure when to break off from the main thread, so sometimes I never actually read them at all. Similar to the disjointed style in *New Scientist* (*Time* may be more familiar if you're US), but at least in those the 'supplementary' text/diagrams are big enough to draw you in when you reach the end of a paragraph in the main article.

Comment: I think it is certainly appropriate as a stylistic element in emails as well. Although the technical necessity of a _post scriptum_ addition may be obsolete, placing something in a "P.S." emphasizes its being an afterthought, which is an expression in itself.

Comment: @WAF: All sounds like pretty subtle nuancing for an email. We're not talking carefully-crafted prose here.

Comment: Sometimes I use P.S. even though I know from the start I want to say it. But what I'm going to say in the P.S. is so separate from the email, that it's just clearer if you keep it separate. That's the kind of sentence that you should probably be sending another email just to say that. But being a short sentence, it's not worth a hassle. If you want to put it in the body, you may write it as a `By the way,` write before signing. So putting it in the body doesn't really make it more organized.

Comment: An example: _Dear professor, Something something about the conference that you are making me organize. I did this and that and I think by that time everything would be ready. More and more talk about that conference. Sincerely, Shahbaz.  P.S. I'm half-way through my thesis_

Comment: Some emails are carefully crafted prose. We use a P.S. on automated emails thanking a donor upon payment to remind them that their donation might be tax-deductible. We don't want to cover it in the body of the email because such a business-oriented note, from a communications standpoint, diminishes the emphasis we want to place on the act of charitable giving. Email can be as formal as a letter, and a lot of businesses & organizations are using it for "official" communication because it saves money on postage. Don't assume email is always informal.

Answer (score 5):

As [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) already noted, the *post scriptum* should appear after the main body of the text, perhaps even after the signature.  With that said, I do agree with FumbleFingers that the construct *likely* has no place in E-mail.

I would like to additionally point out that there is another use for P.S. besides adding a new thought to the correspondence: I have often seen P.S. used in E-mails to incite a new thread of conversation that is tangent to the main topic.  While I think that might be a legitimate use in other forms of correspondence, it is generally considered bad [netiquette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette) when used in E-mail.  Although the rule was not written in [the original RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1855), it is generally considered bad form to change the topic of an E-mail thread; topics should be changed by sending a separate E-mail, thus starting a new thread.

With that said, in rare cases I think the P.S. construct *might* be acceptable if used like a footnote, *i.e.*, to provide some additional clarification on something from the main body of text that is likely unnecessary, and would otherwise hamper the flow of the main text.

Comment: Well I did specifically say *never really 'appropriate'* rather than just *never appropriate*, and I think you've identified some aspects of 'excusable' exceptions. I don't do work emails much these days, but I always preferred a second email to receiving one email with an unrelated addendum. I really do think it's often just lack of consideration for people who might want/need to deal with things in an orderly and efficient manner.

Comment: I do use it in emails if the email itself is a formal business message, but the recipient is also a friend outside work. This makes it easy for them to forward on work related content while stripping out personal stuff, eg. Attached are those reports your Director asked for, yada yada, regards, Rory. p.s. You up for a beer after work?

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Haha glad I didn't work with you then. Maybe I'm anal, but I'd rather have the bit about the beer on a separate email. Or a call would have been better. Besides, what if I wanted to forward the work stuff to others? No thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I recently used PS and here is an example:

> To: John
> CC: Many people including executives
>
> Subject: How to build a wall
>
> Hi John,
>
> Attached document explains how to build a wall...
>
> 1.
>
> 2.
>
> 3.
>
> 4.
>
> I have also added details on how to get funding...
>
> 1.
>
> 2.
>
> 3.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Tom
>
> PS: I didn't have permissions to add this information to your online document and therefore I have created a separate document. Please feel free to copy/paste this information to your online document.

The main topic of the email is how to build the wall and how to get funding. Why it's not added to the online doc is trivial and most recipients of the email would not care. Therefore, I don't think it needs to be in the main body of the email.

Answer (score 2):

Writers should be careful when if at all using PS at the end of an email.

As previously stated PS was used in pen and ink letters when the writer forgot to include something in the body of the letter - the only option was to try and squeeze it in in between lines or else rewrite the whole thing.

It is so easy to just add anything ommitted to an appropriate part of the main body of the email. Only the sender will know it wasn't included in the first draft.

Be aware if using PS as the receiving person may not see the PS as the email when open  may only fit up to the signature at the bottom of the screen - the reader may not in this case get any inclination that they need to scroll further down because something (which the sender may feel is crucial) was ommitted from the body of the email.

This recently happened to me and the PS was a crucial piece of information which I completely missed casuing the sender to get upset and annoyed as they felt that I deliberately chose to ignore it.

Alternatively as a part-time cynic I may say that maybe the sender deliberately added it as a PS so that I wouldn't pick it up

Answer (score 0):

## Using "P.S." decreases your signal-to-noise ratio and degrades your ability to communicate clearly.

P.S. may be appropriate when using set ink or stone, however, in modern times, **it is archaic** and inexcusable as you can easily move text around.

### As such, PS should never be used in an email.

<sub>(unless you do not care about communicating clearly)</sub>

---

#### By using PS in an email, you have demonstrated a failure to ask:

- What is the point of this email?
- What type of response do I want from it?

If your intention was to find out if someone still enjoyed making clothes,
then your first sentence should have been:

`"Do you still enjoy making clothes?"`

If it wasn't the most pressing issue in the email, than it should have been tied closely to the sentence that was.

Otherwise, if you were just curious, say so:

`"I'm curious, do you still enjoy making clothes?"`

---

Refs:

http://www.nature.com/scitable/ebooks/english-communication-for-scientists-14053993
http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424127887324735104578117193149868504
https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9226/using-p-s-in-a-formal-email#

Comment: Depends on the email. P.S is valid in an informal email, and is also acceptable when content after the P.S is completely unrelated to the email body.

Comment: Do you have any particular basis for concluding that "PS should never be used in an email?"

Comment: @PraveshParekh yes, PS is sloppy; it rescues your signal-to-noise by making it less clear what the purpose of your email was as a PS comment may be an entirely different subject matter (and perhaps should be a different email) or an aside, or something you thought of that needs an urgent response.  Not using it forces you to decide where in the message the information is actually appropriate, and help you make it more clear as to why that information is there.

Comment: That is your personal opinion. Where exactly have you read that PS is sloppy and should never be used?

Comment: @PraveshParekh references added just for you.

Comment: @CLockeWork even in informal email you should want to be clear; using PS reduces clarity.

Comment: Actually it can increase clarity by not including things that are very short, and unconnected to the body, in the body. As an afterthought to the email body I agree that we should revisit what we wrote. However, saying such things as "P.S - Please give Janie my love." would be acceptable in an informal email.

Comment: @CLockeWork in that instance it's trivial to put `Please give Janie my love.` directly before the closing (with no P.S.) - thereby reducing the noise of a straggling sentence after your closing.

Comment: In a quick, informal email? Your basis of noise reduction is a factor most people are never going to notice let alone care about. I would say that the visual structure (the post script being used to separate trivial and unconnected appendices) is more important.

Answer (score 0):

P.S could be used when you are trying to convey something which is not appropriate to the subject mentioned and still needed to be included to the same mail.

Answer (score -6):

PS stands for "Please see" in the e-mails, to highlight something important. There is no need of Post script in the e-mails. Post script is outdated technique which was used in earlier days when there were no e-mails.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think "please see" is the "P.S." that the original poster intended - particularly as OP accepted a "post scriptum" answer.